# How can I add the Android Emulator to Plank dock in 19.04?

Tags: android-studio, dock, emulation, plank, android-emulator

I'm using the [Plank](https://launchpad.net/plank) dock (v.0.11.4) for my apps in Ubuntu 19.04.  The Android Emulator (opened from [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)) does not appear next to the other open applications.

Is it possible to show it in the dock as an independent application?

(The weird part is that it DOES appear in the alt+tab menu but not in the dock itself)

The emulator can be launched from the terminal as well with the command:

> emulator -avd emulator_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch the app from the GNOME menu; its icon will appear on the right side of the dock. Right-click on it and select "Keep in dock" to make them appear permanently.

Comment: The emulator does not appear in the GNOME menu, it's either launched from Android Studio or via the terminal

Comment: Then you may need to add it to the GNOME Menu, using the CLI launch command you provided, to get it to where you can do "Keep in dock". Wish I had a better answer, but the Plank documentation is kinda not there.

Comment: Unfortunately that's exactly my initial question.

Comment: If you launch it from the terminal, is there a "Keep in dock" option when you Alt-Tab back to the Desktop?

Comment: You're right, it worked. Even though it's not directly from Android Studio and it's kind of an annoying workaround. Thanks!